# Bulk Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have multiple spread-sheets, each with the same columns.

I also have a Word template prepped for Mail Merge.

I'd like to automatically have the merge go through each spreadsheet in a directory and have it create one file (Word) for each spreadsheet.

Does anyone have any thoughts about the first step of this process? I've dug into GSuite/Docs, Python and can't find a simple way. I'll code myself if I have to, but I'd prefer to find some sort of built-in method so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is to create a single spreadsheet with all of the entries so that the mail merge is pulling from a si gle place. How you merge these sheets will be the automated part. It can be as simple as copying the content of the individual sheets to a single sheet, or writing a macro to pull the content together.